# docker: Error response from daemon: path / is mounted on / but it is not a shared or slave mount

Tags: windows, docker, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to run `node-exporter` using `docker run -d --net="host" --pid="host" -v "/:/host:ro,rslave" quay.io/prometheus/node-exporter:latest --path.rootfs=/host` command.


Source of this command is : https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#docker

Using the aforementioned command image is downloaded successfully. 
Though I am getting a error response as :
`docker: Error response from daemon: path / is mounted on / but it is not a shared or slave mount.`
[image]

**My system config :**
Windows 10, 
Docker version : v20.10.17

Comment: "The Windows exporter is recommended for Windows users." --> https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#node-exporter

Comment: Thank you so much @RickRackow, I was so into Docker images and containers, that I missed it. Thank you for saving my day. 
Really appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was using the Linux exporter in the windows. 

**Learning:**

- For Linux system, we have `node-exporter` for monitoring metrics.
- For Windows system, we have `wmi-exporter` for monitoring metrics

**Link for Window exporter** : https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter
Thanks to @rick-rachow for your valuable comment.